# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 Foreign Key Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm learning Django.
I have two models as follows:

```
class IdentificationAddress(models.Model):
    id_ident_address = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ident = models.ForeignKey('Ident', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ident')
    address = models.TextField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'identification_address'


class IdentC(models.Model):
    id_ident = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ident = models.TextField(unique=True)
    name = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ident'
```

I am using the Django debugger:

```
python manage.py shell
```

and import the model

```
from invent.models import IdentC as identity
from invent.models import IdentificationAddress as ident_Address
```

I can access the name of a specific identity

```
indentity.objects.filter(ident='00LD').values('name')
```

it returns

```
<QuerySet [{'name': u'Joss'}]>
```

Then I can access information of a specific address:

```
ident_Address.objects.filter(address='LOC23').values().last()
```

it returns

```
{'times': u'{"2017-07-16"}', u'ident_id': u'00LD', 'address': u'LOC23', 'id_ident_address': 217}
```

but I get an error when I try to use any identity

```
ident_Address.objects.filter(ident='00LD').values()
```

or

```
ident_Address.objects.filter(ident_id='00LD').values()
```

error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '00LD'
```

If I try this in postgres

```
SELECT * FROM identification_address WHERE ident= '00LD'
```

I don't have any problem.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance
**NOTE**: For the sake of clarity, I've changed the name of the Ident model to IdentC

Comment: I've tried: <br>   

    ident_Address.objects.filter(ident__name='Joss').values()

<br>  It shows this error

<br>   ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: text = integer
    LINE 1: ...n_c" ON ("identification_address"."ident" = "ident...
                                                                 ^
<br>    HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 0):

You try to match '00LD' with the field `id` of `Ident`.
Or in your first example you wrote :
`indentity.objects.filter(ident='00LD').values('name')`
'00LD' match with `ident` field of `Ident`

So you can filter like this :
`ident_Address.objects.filter(ident__ident='00LD').values()`
First ident represent your model, and the second one, the field of `Ident`.

If you want to filter ident_Address by Ident name :
`ident_Address.objects.filter(ident__name='Joss').values()`

Comment: Hi Wilfried.    <br/> I've tried the first option   _ident_Address.objects.filter(ident__ident='00LD').values()_    **FieldError:   Cannot resolve keyword 'ident' into field. Choices are: id_ident_address, address, ident, ident_id, time.**   
I've tried change ident for Ident the same error.  The second instruction generates the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In Django, when you want to access some field in ForeignKey table, you should use `__` (Double underscore). For your case, it will be

```
ident_Address.objects.filter(ident__id_ident='00LD')
```

Comment: Hi M Hassan.  I've tried your suggestion but i fails.  **FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'ident' into field. Choices are: id_ident_address, address, ident, ident_id, time**

Comment: You have to provide ID of required object in `IdentC` table. I just write ID you provide in your question. You should give integer as ID here.

Comment: Hi. It does not work for me if I do not have lookup.... that's why I have to put _iexact_

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.
Sorry @Exprator I'm learning how to use the answer field, as well.
So I started debugging how Django queries are translated to SQL queries. Then I found the solution:

```
ident_Address.objects.filter(ident__id_ident__iexact='00LD').values()
```

Where first *ident* means field *ident* in *IdentificationAddress* model and *id_ident* field in *identC* model